# GCC plugin injecting code as text into current translation unit

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

I'm creating a GCC plugin that needs to inject code as text into the current translation unit before it is even preprocessed.

This code is non-trivial and is dynamically generated from an external file supplied to the plugin.

I know it is possible to build_decl etc. to inject nodes into the AST to achieve the same effect upon PLUGIN_START_UNIT but I would imagine it is simply easier to just inject the code as text right before GCC processes it.

Another way would be to write a separate program to merge the generated code and the translation unit into an intermediate file before passing to GCC but that would skew the line numbers somewhat.

Would this be possible via GCC plugin?

Comment: Have an external program emit #line directives and be fully compiler-agnostic.

Comment: Ah. The plugin already does a lot of other things. I only wanted to add this to it because I dont want another program just for this tiny feature.